# Case insensitive query that returns case sensitive data with Hibernate and mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

In my REST-api I am using Spring Boot with a mysql database. One of my entities has a string name as its primary key. When I query the corresponding table, the query is case insensitive per default. That's all good, but mysql returns the primary key cased exactly like typed in the query. For example:

```
findOne("John") returns:
{"name": "John",
 "age": 21}
```

and

```
findOne("joHn") returns:
{"name": "joHn",
 "age": 21}
```

Is there a way to query query the database case insensitively, and have it return the primary key exactly as it reads in the database? So that, for example, findOne("JOHN") would return {"name": "John"}.

I've seen a similar question posted here before, where the solution was just to use toLowerCase(), but obviously that doesn't cut it here.

Comment: try using `COLLATE` in your query

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, you should try using the *IgnoreCase* for Case Insensitive Queries.

Now, suppose we want to perform a case-insensitive search to find all passengers with a given firstName.

To do so, we'll define our PassengerRepository as:

```
public interface PassengerRepository extends JpaRepository<Passenger, Long> {
    List<Passenger> findByFirstNameIgnoreCase(String firstName);
}
```

Here, the IgnoreCase keyword ensures that the query matches are case insensitive.

Refer the following link for more details :: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-case-insensitive-queries